# Telemetry and Fennec

Tags: android, firefox, browser, metrics, concept

I'd like to know about the concepts and meanings of metrics as follows:

- HTTP_PAGE_COMPLETE_LOAD
- HTTP_PAGE_COMPLETE_LOAD_NET
- HTTP_PAGE_FIRST_SENT_TO_LAST_RECEIVED
- HTTP_PAGE_OPEN_TO_FIRST_SENT
- TOTAL_CONTENT_PAGE_LOAD_TIME
- FENNEC_STARTUP_TIME_JAVAUI

Someone please could suggest others sources to learn more them.

Please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are page navigation timing measurements which map to the [Navigation Timing Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#sec-navigation-timing-interface) and benchmarks:

> Telemetry monitors real-life efficiency of the cache, hence by monitoring the right values we can ensure that improvements we see in the lab also benefit real users. Exactly which measurements we need is not entirely clear yet (work is in progress to determine this).
>
> An important point is that in order to verify results like this we must measure the same (or at least very similar) values in microbenchmarks and in telemetry.

Use the about URI `about:telemetry` to see for yourself.

Here is the meaning of each:

- HTTP_PAGE_COMPLETE_LOAD - the time when the load event of the current document is completed.
- HTTP_PAGE_COMPLETE_LOAD_NET - the network time taken to load all page objects
- HTTP_PAGE_FIRST_SENT_TO_LAST_RECEIVED - the difference between the time the first request for an object(image, script, audio, video, iframe) is made and the time the last object is received
- HTTP_PAGE_OPEN_TO_FIRST_SENT - the difference between the time the TCP connection is opened and the time the first byte of the response from the server is received
- TOTAL_CONTENT_PAGE_LOAD_TIME - the total time (request, response, processing, event handling) to load all objects on the page
- FENNEC_STARTUP_TIME_JAVAUI - the time from the click of the Firefox icon to start of the UI thread

[image: Navigation Timing Illustration]

**References**

- [Necko/MobileCache/MicroBenchmarks - MozillaWiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Necko/MobileCache/MicroBenchmarks)
- [Resource Timing Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/)
- [Performance Timeline](https://www.w3.org/TR/performance-timeline/)
- [User Timing](https://www.w3.org/TR/user-timing/)
- [Understanding the Real-World Performance of your Web Application Across IE11 and Other Browsers – IEBlog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2013/12/12/understanding-the-real-world-performance-of-your-web-application-across-ie11-and-other-browsers/)
- [Mozilla Bug 661881 – Implement about:telemetry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=661881)
- [About protocol links - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About_Protocol_Links)
- [Mozilla Bugzilla Advanced Search](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/query.cgi?format=advanced)
- [Mozilla Bug List Advanced Search Results - Summary: fennec, Status: RESOLVED, Component: Telemetry, Resolution: FIXED](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?short_desc=fennec&resolution=FIXED&query_format=advanced&bug_status=RESOLVED&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&component=Telemetry)
- [http_page_complete_load - Google Site Search](https://www.google.com/search?sitesearch=bugzilla.mozilla.org&q=HTTP_PAGE_COMPLETE_LOAD)
- [Telemetry Dashboards](https://telemetry.mozilla.org/)